# SharePoint 2010. The opportunity to edit the code

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, permissions, master-page, css

What rights the user should have to edit code in SharePoint Designer 2010? It is necessary to modify the html, css and  write jQuery scripts. 
Now I can't even edit a masterpage

Comment: what do you mean by Code??

Answer (score 5):

You will need Full Control permission level to be able to edit a MasterPage in SharePoint Designer 2010.

Reference: [User permissions and permission levels (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074(v=office.14).aspx)